# Looking for way to diagnose sporadic unintended 302, 301 redirects

Tags: asp.net, redirect, webforms, pageload

I am getting sporadic redirects from a requested page (e.g. GET /BlogJT1?pid=5) to /Default.  There are NO explicit redirects to default.aspx in the BlogJT1 server-side code.  This is a sample of the IIS log:

#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0

```
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2023-04-24 20:39:01
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2023-04-24 20:38:59 192.168.1.75 GET /BlogJT1 pid=7&id=93c6b073-4bc6-4a3f-9810-2ee5cb2042bd 80 - XX.XX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/112.0.0.0+Safari/537.36 - 302 0 0 3788
2023-04-24 20:38:59 192.168.1.75 GET /Default - 80 - XX.XX.XXX.XXX Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;
```

(the XX.XX.XXX.XXX is redacted host address).  I have tried using Fiddler to see more detail of the reasoning behind the redirect, but either I don't know how to use it completely or it just can't provide that info.   Not sure how to proceed.